# python GUI frameworks that support touch devices

Tags: application-development, python, gui, touchscreen, pyqt

Hello everyone I want to know what is the best GUI framework for python that supports
touch I've been searching couple of hours and this are results which I found:

## PyQt5

I heard for Qt and I know it supports touch screen devices but I was searching for reviews about PyQt5 (5.2) support for touch devices and didn't found anything specific.

## Kivy

I found out about Kivy 10 minutes ago I watched some videos ,read their documentation and
I was really impressed.

## PYGTK3

I found on wiki that version 3 supports touch devices but I wanted to confirm that and didn't found anything specific too.

I want to hear your opinion esspecially I need to know which of those solution is best to combine with gstreamer framework.

Comment: Is this for development for Ubuntu on Phones (Unity8 & Mir), or for the traditional desktop (Unity7/Compiz & X11)?

Comment: Well primary I wanna develop  for ubuntu desktop enviroment but everything else is welcome too.I would be grateful if some of you could post your opinions , experiance and recomendations Iam sure you could help many people out there who are scratching their head when this topic pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [pyotherside](http://pyotherside.readthedocs.org/), it's not really a GUI framework for python but a way to call python3 code from a QML application (you could even use the [Ubuntu SDK](https://askubuntu.com/tags/ubuntu-sdk/info)).

[Pyotherside](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/pyotherside) is available in the Ubuntu repositories as of 14.10.

Regarding Gstreamer, from python I'd use gobject introspection, See [Using GStreamer 1.0 from Python](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0#Using_GStreamer_1.0_from_Python).

From QML, if you just need the playback feature, take a look at the [MediaPlayer QML Type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html).

Comment: Thx a lot for response it's my first time to hear about pyotherside .I'll look into it as for pyqt ,pyqtk or kivy did you use any of them ?

Comment: I'm not sure about touch support in pyQt and pyGTK3. I never used  kivy. So my only recommendation is pyotherside. Sorry I'm not really familiar with the others.

Comment: No problem mate your showed me new alternative .Thanks a lot.

Comment: I forgot to mention that a 14.04 version of pyotherside exists in our [dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~checkbox-dev/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). If you think my proposal can help you, don't forget to accept my answer. Thx